# Capture incoming SMS

Tags: sms, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

how can i access to incoming sms in windows Phone 7.5 (mango)? is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, you can't do it using the supplied API - it doesn't allow it.

I know that there may be features of the ecosystem use text messaging under the covers, but these are handled at a much lower level than the APIs allow you to access.  It is similar to the way that you don't have access to incoming call data, and hence why the WM6.5 call filter type of app is not available in WP7

Answer (score 1):

NO Sorry as of now MS is not provided any API for SMS access. May be in future it may provide.

Comment: I don't think they will provide this access in future either.  The whole reasoning is to ensure the privacy of the user's data.  Allowing access to the SMS store is outside what MS consider to be reasonable to access in an app.

Comment: Correct, you are right but i heard from the user review board response of WP7 , that may be  in next release they may provide access to SMS for simply operation like creating and Sending and reading.